# How can I plot a DiagrammeR flowchart with different connector types?

Tags: r, diagrammer

I am trying to find a way to create flowchart with different type connectors using DiagrammeR package. This is the output I would like to get.

[image]

Below is the code I have presently:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
DiagrammeR("graph TB;
A-->B;
A---C;
A---D;
B-->E;
B---F
")
```

Answer (score -1):

Check out this webpage: https://github.com/mermaidjs/mermaid-gitbook/blob/master/content/flowchart.md. To create the dashed line between C and D use the following code:

```
  library(DiagrammeR)
    DiagrammeR("graph TB;
               A-->B;
               A---C;
               A---D;
               B-->E;
               B---F;
               C-.->D")
```